# Spring MVC: No message found under code for locale 'en_US'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

Dispatcher-servlet.xml;

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"> <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" /> <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> </bean>
```

I have messages_en.properties under /resources/messages_en.properties

```
label.meetingDescription=Meeting Description
```

In my JSP, I am using like

```
<form:label path="meetingDiscription">
        <spring:message code="label.meetingDescription" />
</form:label>
```

I am getting error;

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: NoNo message found under code 'label.meetingDescription' for locale 'en_US'
```

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.meetingDescription' for locale 'en_US'

Comment: Check if the message file is really in the classpath when you build de project.

Comment: Where is the resources folder where you have put this properties file?
If its in the webapp folder then this won't work. You need to put this folder in the java class path.

Comment: no,my resourses folder is not in webapp folder

Comment: can i use two property file in my project..???

Comment: Absolutely.  You can, for example, create one called messages_es.properties that contains all your messages translated to Spanish and configure Spring to switch based on the selected language.  A simple Google search can get you plenty of information on it.

Answer (score 4):

You should place the "messages_en.properties" in the path /src/main/resources. Then it will be accesible by the compiled classes.
Besides you should create another file called "messages.properties", which is used when the default Locale language is used (property defaulLocale of SessionLocaleResolver defined in "dispatcher-servlet.xml").

Comment: I only have default Locale which is again english. The file name is applicationlable.properties and I am getting  javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'pagelabel.app.name' for locale 'en_US'. I kept the file in  /src/main/resources .

Answer (score -2):

Just move "messages_en properties" directly to webapp folder